# Disable scroll down to dismiss on FullScreen Cover in Swift / SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi I wanted to know if its possible to disable the drag down gesture to dismiss the full screen cover in swift / swiftui.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVFoundation
import CropViewController

final class CameraModel: ObservableObject {
    private let service = CameraService()
    
    @Published var photo: Photo!
    
    @Published var showAlertError = false
    
    @Published var isFlashOn = false
    
    @Published var willCapturePhoto = false
    
    var alertError: AlertError!
    
    var session: AVCaptureSession
    
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        self.session = service.session
        
        service.$photo.sink { [weak self] (photo) in
            guard let pic = photo else { return }
            self?.photo = pic
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        
        service.$shouldShowAlertView.sink { [weak self] (val) in
            self?.alertError = self?.service.alertError
            self?.showAlertError = val
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        
        service.$flashMode.sink { [weak self] (mode) in
            self?.isFlashOn = mode == .on
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        
        service.$willCapturePhoto.sink { [weak self] (val) in
            self?.willCapturePhoto = val
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
    }
    
    func configure() {
        service.checkForPermissions()
        service.configure()
        //service.changeCamera()

    }
    
    func capturePhoto() {
        if photo != nil {
            self.photo = nil
        }
        service.capturePhoto()
    }
    
    func flipCamera() {
        service.changeCamera()
    }
    
    func zoom(with factor: CGFloat) {
        service.set(zoom: factor)
    }
    
    func switchFlash() {
        service.flashMode = service.flashMode == .on ? .off : .on
    }
    func resetPhoto(){
        if photo != nil {
            self.photo = nil
        }
    }
}

struct CameraView: View {
    @StateObject var model = CameraModel()
    
    @State var currentZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    @StateObject var registerData = RegisterViewModel()

    @StateObject var newPostData = NewPostModel()
    
    enum SheetType {
        case imagePick
        case imageCrop
        case share
    }
    
    @State private var currentSheet: SheetType = .imagePick
    @State private var actionSheetIsPresented = false
    @State private var sheetIsPresented = false
    
    @State private var originalImage: UIImage?
    @State private var image: UIImage?
    @State private var croppingStyle = CropViewCroppingStyle.default
    @State private var croppedRect = CGRect.zero
    @State private var croppedAngle = 0


    var captureButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
            impactMed.impactOccurred()
            model.capturePhoto()
        }, label: {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65, alignment: .center)
                )
        })
    }
    
    var capturedPhotoThumbnail: some View {

        Group {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .frame(width: 55, height: 55, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                   // newPostData.picker.toggle()
                    self.croppingStyle = .default
                    self.currentSheet = .imagePick
                    self.sheetIsPresented = true
                })
                .overlay(
                    Image("gallery")
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("white")))

                .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented) {
                    if (self.currentSheet == .imagePick) {
                        ImagePickerView(croppingStyle: self.croppingStyle, sourceType: .photoLibrary, onCanceled: {
                            // on cancel
                        }) { (image) in
                            guard let image = image else {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            self.originalImage = image
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.currentSheet = .imageCrop
                                self.sheetIsPresented = true
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (self.currentSheet == .imageCrop) {
                        ZStack {
                            Color("imagecropcolor").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            ImageCropView(croppingStyle: self.croppingStyle, originalImage: self.originalImage!, onCanceled: {
                                // on cancel
                            }) { (image, cropRect, angle) in
                                // on success
                                self.image = image
                                model.resetPhoto()
                                newPostData.newPost.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
       
      
    }
    
    var flipCameraButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
            impactMed.impactOccurred()
            model.flipCamera()
        }, label: {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                .overlay(
                    Image(systemName: "camera.rotate.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.white))
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ZStack {
                Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack {
                    HStack{
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            model.switchFlash()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: model.isFlashOn ? "bolt.fill" : "bolt.slash.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                        })
                        .accentColor(model.isFlashOn ? .yellow : .white)
                        .padding(.leading, 30)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        if model.photo != nil {
                            Text("taken photo").onAppear{
                                newPostData.newPost.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                        //                Image(uiImage: model.photo.image!)
                        //                    .resizable()
                        //                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        //                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        //                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                        //                    .animation(.spring())
                        //
                    }
                  
                    
                    CameraPreview(session: model.session)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture().onChanged({ (val) in
                                //  Only accept vertical drag
                                if abs(val.translation.height) > abs(val.translation.width) {
                                    //  Get the percentage of vertical screen space covered by drag
                                    let percentage: CGFloat = -(val.translation.height / reader.size.height)
                                    //  Calculate new zoom factor
                                    let calc = currentZoomFactor + percentage
                                    //  Limit zoom factor to a maximum of 5x and a minimum of 1x
                                    let zoomFactor: CGFloat = min(max(calc, 1), 5)
                                    //  Store the newly calculated zoom factor
                                    currentZoomFactor = zoomFactor
                                    //  Sets the zoom factor to the capture device session
                                    model.zoom(with: zoomFactor)
                                }
                            })
                        )
                        .onAppear {
                            model.configure()
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented: $model.showAlertError, content: {
                            Alert(title: Text(model.alertError.title), message: Text(model.alertError.message), dismissButton: .default(Text(model.alertError.primaryButtonTitle), action: {
                                model.alertError.primaryAction?()
                            }))
                        })
                        .overlay(
                            Group {
                                if model.willCapturePhoto {
                                    Color.black
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        capturedPhotoThumbnail
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        captureButton
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        flipCameraButton
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)

                    
                    
                }
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $newPostData.newPost) {
                if model.photo == nil {
                    NewPost(imageData: (self.image?.pngData())! )
                    
                } else {
                    NewPost(imageData: model.photo.originalData)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I've added my full code showing both the.fullscreencover at the bottom of the CameraView along with the .sheet for the image picker

I don't want to dismiss NewView() by dragging down from the top. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: It should be disabled by default..

Comment: For some reason, its letting me drag down from the top to dismiss

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? Also it would be helpful if you could upload a gif/recording :)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 12.5.1, Swift 5.4, and running on an iOS 14.5 simulator. Here is the gif recording: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/fLHPOvHlNlZvld6kUg. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's not a `.fullscreencover`. Are you sure you aren't using `.sheet` somewhere? Try searching using `Command` + `Shift` + `F`.

Comment: I'm using a .sheet for an image picker earlier in the code that I pass as an image for this NewView(). But for this view specifically, I'm using the .fullscreencover

Comment: Possibly the sheet might be overriding the fullscreencover... Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Is it not possible to use a .fullscreencover and a .sheet in the same parent view?

Comment: No, it should be possible

Comment: Yea I'm pretty confused. I have added my entire parent code view that has the .fullscreencover and the .sheet for the image picker